# Customer 360 Audiences Web and Mobile Application JSON Schema

Tags: json, schema

I have gone through the following documentation regarding creating an Event Type JSON schema for the mobile or web application connector in Customer 360 Audiences:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.c360_a_schema_best_practices.htm&type=5

However, it doesn't provide enough details about what the JSON schema file should contain to be considered valid, and all the JSON schema files I tried were invalid when uploaded to Customer 360 Audiences.

Does anyone have any idea?